# Webp image upload issue in paperclip gem in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, webp, open-uri, paperclip-validation

webp images upload not supported it's giving this error message when trying to upload webp images has below

avatar_2_3_webp = open(image_ur)

at paperclip method "open" we are getting this error

ImageSpec::Error (#Paperclip::Tempfile:/tmp/18c5a2261d1d178068acb724a8a967b720221108-1242657-rpwwg520221108-1242657-n7zd3k.webp is not a supported image format. Sorry bub :():

we are using Rails 4.2 and ruby 2.3.0
paperclip (4.2.4)
paperclip-compression (0.3.11)
paperclip-optimizer (2.0.0)
ImageMagick 6.9.10-23

please help on this to how to fix this issue

I have search so many articles and try with different methods but it's not working

Comment: Imagemagick does not have webp installed. You need to install the webp delegate library. See https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/download

Comment: libwebp is install and again same error  @fmw42

Comment: Ask on Paperclip/Rails/Ruby forum. Does not look like an Imagemagick error message.